# Unable to resolve service for type IDatabase interface when activate HomeController class

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, interface

I am encountering an error while running my program with `.NET Core 7.0` on `Windows 11`.

**The Exception Message:**

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
'MoviesCore.Controllers.IDatabase' while attempting to activate
'MoviesCore.Controllers.HomeController'.
```

Below is the `HomeController` class and the `IDatabase` interface it depends upon:

```cs
namespace MoviesCore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController: Controller
    {
        const int SUCCESS = 1;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        //private readonly MovieDBContext _context;
        private readonly IDatabase _database;

        public HomeController (ILogger<HomeController> logger, IDatabase database)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            //_context = context;
            _database = database;
        }
    }
}

namespace MoviesCore.Interfaces
{
    public interface IDatabase
    {
        Task<int> CheckCatInMovie (int MovieID,int CategoryID);
        Task<IList<CategoryLU>> GetCategories ();
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of the `IDatabase` interface in the `Database` class:

```cs
namespace MoviesCore.Services
{
    public class Database : IDatabase
    {
        private readonly MovieDBContext _context;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IReadRepo _readRepo;

        public Database (MovieDBContext context, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IReadRepo readRepo)
        {
            _context = context;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _readRepo = readRepo;
        }

        public async Task<int> CheckCatInMovie(int MovieID, int CategoryID)
        {
            IList<MovieCategory> categories = await _unitOfWork.ReadRepo.GetListWithPredicate<MovieCategory>(mc => mc.MovieID == MovieID && mc.CategoryLUID == CategoryID);
            return categories.Count;
        }

        public async Task<IList<CategoryLU>> GetCategories ()
        {
            IList<CategoryLU> categories = await _unitOfWork.ReadRepo.GetList<CategoryLU> ();
            return categories;
        }
     }
}
```

This is the definition for the `DbContext` implementation, `MovieDBContext`:

```cs
namespace Api.Models
{
    public class MovieDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public MovieDBContext(DbContextOptions<MovieDBContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public MovieDBContext () { }

        //dbset statements might not be needed
        public DbSet<Movie>? Movie { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieCategory>? MovieCategory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieNamesPosition>? MovieNamesPosition { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PositionsLU>? PositionLU { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NamesLU>? NamesLU { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CategoryLU>? CategoryLU { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie>? spSearchMovies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<spGetCats>? spGetCats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the code from `Program.cs` where services for the application are added:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder (args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Logging.ClearProviders ();
builder.Logging.AddConsole ();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews ();
builder.Services.AddMvc ();
//builder.Services.AddDbContext<MovieDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:SQLConnection"));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MovieDBContext> (opt =>opt.UseSqlServer ("Server = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog = MoviesCore;Integrated Security = True;"));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IReadRepo, ReadRepo>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork> ();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDatabase,MoviesCore.Services.Database> ();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor,HttpContextAccessor> ();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages ();

var app = builder.Build ();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment ())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler ("/Shared/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts ();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection ();
app.UseStaticFiles ();

app.UseRouting ();

app.UseAuthorization ();
app.MapRazorPages ();

app.MapControllerRoute (
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run ();
```

I couldn't find out what causes the problem. Can anyone help me to find out what the issue is?

Comment: Looks fine on the surface. Are you sure you don't have two different `IDatabase` interfaces or something like that?

Comment: It looks like you have two `IDatabase` interfaces. The error message is about `MoviesCore.Controllers.IDatabase` but the one you've shown is `MoviesCore.Interfaces.IDatabase`. You're registering the latter but depending on the former in the controller.

Comment: It looks like the Dependency Injection container wasn't able to get the service for the **IDatabase** interface when trying to active the **HomeController** class. Since you've mapped **IDatabase** interface in the **Program.cs** file, I would check some common mistakes. Is there a circular dependency? Are the namespaces fine? Are the dependencies correct in **Database** class?